# ASP.NET save image to SQL Server without page refresh

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server-2008

On the client side I need to save an image, user only select file by input (type=file).

1. I want to save without page fresh, or post back.
2. I use page method to save other data, I collect everything and convert to Json and send by page method. Is it possible to save image with other data?
3. I must work by IE (less than 10), so I can't use html 5.
4. I found some jQuery plugin but I can't use them in asp.net. They usually call php server side.
5. It's difficult for me to read in save image from SQL Server too.
6. It would be great if I get image in client, convert to json, and send then convert to byte and save in SQL Server

Comment: What is your question exactly? Do you have sample code?

Comment: Please try with the AsyncFileUpload. http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx

Comment: use Jquery Uploadify ..................

Comment: @codemonkeh i don't have sample code, but infact i can upload and save file after postback. but in this case i need upload and save without postback.

Comment: @raman uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/) as i check is html5, and i need to work by ie 7,8,9.

Comment: @MohammadAdibi dear it has two versions flash and html 5, you can go for flash version

Comment: @raman: For flash version, client must have to install flash player plugin which is not a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

File upload needs a full postback. use hidden iframe/form to do the postback to upload the file to the server.

Below is the sample code.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" size="15" name="file" onchange="UploadPicture(this, 'user-picture-form');" class="upload-new-avatar"/>

<img id="Myimg" src="" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
function UploadPicture(sender, form) {
    var newForm = $("<FORM>");
    newForm.attr({ method: "POST", enctype: "multipart/form-data" }).hide();
    newForm.appendTo($("body"));

    var $this = $(sender), $clone = $this.clone();
    $this.after($clone).appendTo($(newForm));

    AjaxFormSubmit({
        type: "POST",
        validate: false,
        parentControl: $(newForm),
        form: $(newForm),
        messageControl: null,
        throbberPosition: { my: "left center", at: "right center", of: sender, offset: "5 0" },
        url: '/Home/UploadPicture',
        success: function (data) {            
            if (data.Status == ActionStatus.Successfull) {
                if (data.Results == null || data.Results == 'null') {
                    //Message(data.Message, ActionStatus.Error);
                }
                else {
                    $("#Myimg").attr("src", "/Images/" + data.Results[0]);                    
                }
            }
            else {
                //Message(data.Message, ActionStatus.Error);                
            }
        }
    });
}

function AjaxFormSubmit(parameters) {
    /*=====================================Sample Usage======================================================
    AjaxFormSubmit({
    type: "POST",                                                                                       //default is "POST"
    validate: true,                                                                                     //if the form/data needs to be validated
    validationError: function () { },                                                                   //called only if validate is true
    parentControl: $(selector),                                                                         //required if validate is true
    error: function () { },                                                                             //called when an unexpected error occurs
    form:  $(selector),                                                                                 //neglected if data is not null
    data: {name: "value"}                                                                               //overwrites the form parameter
    messageControl:  $(selector),                                                                       //the control where the status message needs to be displayed
    beforeSubmit: function (arr, $form, options) { },                                                   //called before the form is actually submitted 
    throbberPosition: { my: "left center", at: "right center", of: sender, offset: "5 0" },             //the position at which the throbber needs to be displayed 
    url: url,                                                                                           //the url that needs to be hit
    success: function (data) {},                                                                        //called after the request has been executed without any unhandeled exception
    bar: $('.bar'),                                                                                     //var bar = $('.bar');
    percent: $('.percent'),                                                                             //var percent = $('.percent');
    status: $('#status')                                                                                //var status = $('#status');
    });
    ===============================================================================================*/

    if (parameters.validate == true) {
        if (ValidateControls($(parameters.messageControl), $(parameters.parentControl)) == false) {
            if (parameters.validationError) parameters.validationError();
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (parameters.data == undefined) {
        $(parameters.form).ajaxForm({
            url: parameters.url,
            dataType: $.browser.msie ? "json" : undefined,
            type: parameters.type == undefined ? "POST" : parameters.type,
            error: function () {
                RemoveThrobber();
                Message("Unexpected Error", ActionStatus.Error);
                if (parameters.error != undefined) parameters.error();
            },
            beforeSubmit: function (arr, form, options) {
                arr = NeglectWaterMark(arr, form);
                if (parameters.beforeSubmit) parameters.beforeSubmit(arr, form, options);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                if (parameters.status != null && parameters.status != undefined) {
                    parameters.status.empty();
                    var percentVal = '0%';
                    parameters.bar.width(percentVal)
                    parameters.percent.html(percentVal);
                }
            },
            uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                parameters.bar.width(percentVal)
                parameters.percent.html(percentVal);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                //RemoveThrobber();
                if (data.Status == undefined) {
                    Message('Invalid data returned in the response', ActionStatus.Error);
                    return false;
                }
                else if (parameters.bar!=null) {
                    var percentVal = '100%';
                    parameters.bar.width(percentVal)
                    parameters.percent.html(percentVal);
                    parameters.success(data);
                }
                else{
                parameters.success(data);
                }
            },
            complete: function (xhr) {

            }
        }).submit();
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: parameters.url,
            type: parameters.type == undefined ? "POST" : parameters.type,
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                RemoveThrobber();
                Message($(parameters.messageControl), "Unexpected Error", ActionStatus.Error);
                if (parameters.error != undefined) parameters.error();
            },
            async: true,
            data: parameters.data,
            success: function (data) {
                RemoveThrobber();
                if (data.Status == undefined) {
                    Message($(parameters.messageControl), "Invalid data returned in the response", ActionStatus.Error);
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    parameters.success(data);
                }
            },
            error: function (obj) {
                Message(data.Message, ActionStatus.Error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public JsonResult UploadPicture(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string newFilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    string fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();

    ActionOutput result;
    if (fileExt == ".jpeg" || fileExt == ".jpg" || fileExt == ".gif" || fileExt == ".bmp" || fileExt == ".png")
    {
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file.InputStream);
        if (bitmap.Height > 600 || bitmap.Height < 200)
        {
            if ((Request.Browser).Browser == "IE")
                return Json(new ActionOutput { Status = ActionStatus.Error, Message = "Image must be between 200x200 to 600x600 pixel." }, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else
                return Json(new ActionOutput { Status = ActionStatus.Error, Message = "Image must be between 200x200 to 600x600 pixel." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        // Saving Image to Folder
        string folder = Server.MapPath("~/Images/");
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(folder))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        file.SaveAs(folder + newFilename);
        result = new ActionOutput { Status = ActionStatus.Successfull, Results = new List<string> { newFilename } };
    }
    else
    {
        result = new ActionOutput { Status = ActionStatus.Error, Message = "Invalid file, valid file are *.jpg, *.jpeg, *.gif, *.bmp, *.png" };     
    }
    if ((Request.Browser).Browser == "IE")
        return Json(result, "text/plain", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    else
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Common Output Class**

```
public class ActionOutput
{
    public ActionStatus Status { get; set; }
    public String Message { get; set; }
    public List<String> Results { get; set; }
}
```

**Don't forget to include Ajax-Form js file (https://github.com/garagesocial/ajax-form-js)**

Comment: is it a tutorial or sample code. i heared this solution but can't find  complete refrence.

Comment: @MohammadAdibi: Check this out. (I am assuming that you are using MVC .net)

Comment: unfortunately no, but i am trying do test it.

Comment: In that case, you should change UploadPicture method only which i have written in controller.

Comment: how to declare controller and common output class,  i convert them to vb, put controller in code behind and common output as a class, but i receive many errors.

Comment: You won't get Json object in return type in code behind, you have to manually create your json and return it as a string and then convert that string into json in javascript function.

Comment: what is JsonResult type it is first error, can i request to help me more, i know you pay more time to write these.

Comment: you have to create a handler and write controller code into that. Example of that code is given in this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-File-Uploads-Gmail-Style-using-JQuery-and-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: i created ashx file, and put : Public Function UploadPicture(file As HttpPostedFileBase) As JsonResult, but first of all give me error for "as JsonResult", can i convert it to string?

Comment: JsonResult class is not available in code behind, its a part of MVC only.

Comment: Check this out http://engthunder.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/uploading-file-using-jquery-with-generic-handler-ashx/

Comment: ajaxForm or gs_ajax_form? i solve handler but the code doesn't work.

Comment: Ajaxform, i have given the link above to download it from github. and if code is not working, means you made some mistakes.

Comment: may i mail you what i write?

Comment: please check yor mail. mohhammad_adibi@hotmail.com

Comment: i got Delivery recipients failed!

Comment: I am getting same error while sending email to you. Delivery to the following recipients failed. mohhammad_adibi@hotmail.com

Comment: it doesn't send zip that contain these files, i changed zip to zi-, and send via hotmail and gmail. please check.

Comment: Its in VB, i am c# developer :)

Comment: thank you so much, if you could send what you written in c#, i'll convert it. if no thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

use post back inside an update panel
please refer this link for more about update panel
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx